# $slice doesn't work in embedded documents in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to use `$slice` operator to return the first 2 elements of `news` in the `feeds` field. this is my schema:

```
...

feeds: {
    shownSize: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    newsSize: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    news: [
      {
        post: ObjectId,
        reason: String,
        score: {
          type: Number,
          default: 0,
        },
      },
    ],
    shown: [
      ObjectId,
    ],
},

...
```

I execute this query: `db.users.find({}, {"feeds.news": {$slice: 2}}).pretty()`, according to the [documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) it should return 2 first elements of `news` array however it return the whole docuemnt!

I guess it is because I executing `$slice` operator in an embedded document but I don't know how to approach my problem in another way.

In simple words I want to return just the first two elements of `news` elements instead of the whole `news` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$slice` only projects the array elements. Use one more projection with the outer field to get the single field.

```
db.users.find({}, { "feeds": 1, "feeds.news": { "$slice": 2 }}).pretty()
```

or you can explicitly remove

```
db.users.find({}, { "feeds.news": { "$slice": 2 }, _id: 0, otherFields: 0 }).pretty()
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked! I had to project "feeds" first